# How to make a bootstrap card to always have the same dimensions

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am making a very simple project in order to learn API calls on Angular, which is working perfectly.
My problem comes with the HTML design. I am using bootstrap 5 to make the design a little bit friendly, but since I have not worked a lot with that library, I still find it difficult to use its classes correctly.
My layout consists in a single card, where I print some text I recieve from the API call, and a button to print another joke. Very simple.
I have already set a maximum height to the card, and it works fine, but my problem comes with the items inside of it.
The string I am printing can have different length, so it will move the button underneath it, which I think is not the best for UI/UX.

I'm providing some code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <h1 class="m-3">{{ actualJoke }}</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg m-5 px-5" (click)="getJoke()">Next joke ⏩</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card {
    height: 40vh;
}
```

What I want to do is to make the button to stay always on the same place, regardless of the size of the container above, but I do not really know if it is possible.

Comment: You can use `position: fixed`.

Comment: @MikePoole Haha I was about to comment the same

Comment: Yep, that does not work, it just puts the button in the middle of everything.

Comment: Based on the class names, I assume the card is styled with "display: flex".
If so you can try to style the button with "margin-top: auto !important", and see what happends. It should then stick to the bottom of the card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content. Some more quick example text for the card's content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this code.

Comment: Is the class "card-title" really important?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="align-items-start card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, pariatur!
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg m-5 px-5 mt-auto" (click)="getJoke()">Next joke
                        ⏩</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="align-items-start card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi a in
                        suscipit, aliquam magnam iure, hic earum autem quasi cum deserunt quidem eos quaerat
                        voluptatum.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg m-5 px-5 mt-auto" (click)="getJoke()">Next joke
                        ⏩</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="align-items-start card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus,
                        laudantium!</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg m-5 px-5 mt-auto" (click)="getJoke()">Next joke
                        ⏩</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want that all buttons have same dimensions then this code will be useful try this.